# Perf tool not detecting TLB misses

Tags: performance, perf, tlb

I'm trying to measure TLB misses in my laptop with the following configuration:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 61
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x1d
cpu MHz     : 1593.625
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap xsaveopt
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4389.43
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

The above is for processor 0 , with similar results for processor 1,2 and 3.

Here's my result for trying to measure TLB misses:

```
perf stat -B -e dTLB-load-misses sleep 2

Performance counter stats for 'sleep 2':

             0      dTLB-load-misses                                            

   2.001923304 seconds time elapsed
```

Not sure how to interpret this. Any insights? I read somewhere that perf doesn't work well on Sandy Bridge laptops...

Comment: I am also surprised that there are none, but ask yourself, what would be generating TLB misses?  You have an idle system that briefly ran a small program with minimal memory traffic.

Comment: Hey, the key point is, any new process is going to populate the tlb first, and incur misses. Doesn't matter if it's a sleep or an echo, right? This happens on real programs too...

Comment: I agree with you, that was why I was surprised there were none.  My point was that your test would only generate a small number of events and therefore you should consider running a test program that accesses lots of data (i.e., a large array).  That should help you understand whether the counter is working on the laptop.

Comment: What is your kernel version?